# Jackson json format currency symbol

Tags: java, json

I have a Java class with a locale and a BigDecimal.  I'm currently serializing the BigDecimal with the @Seralize annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSeralizer.class)
```

My challenge is that I want to add a currency symbol based on the locale in the class to the serialized value.  Is there any way to pass the locale to the serializer?  Or any suggestions on how best to format the data?  The data is retrieved with Spring JDBC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerializerProvider` has a method called `getLocale()`. It returns the default locale (see [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider.html#getLocale%28%29)) but actually it gets the locale information from `SerializationConfig` and you can configure it to get your desired locale using `with` (see [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig.html#with%28java.util.Locale%29)).

**Edit**:
I am not really sure what your `MyCustomSeralizer` looks like but you should write a custom serializer like this

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends SerializerBase<ClassToBeSerialized> {

    public MyCustomSerializer() {
        super(ClassToBeSerialized.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ClassToBeSerialized yourClass,
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        try {
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("big (" + yourClass.getLocale().toString() + ")");
            jsonGenerator.writeString(getLocaleSpecificSerializedValue(yourClass.getBig(), yourClass.getLocale()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

    private String getLocaleSpecificSerializedValue(BigDecimal big, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        return nf.parse(big.toString()).toString();
    }
}
```

Later register it to the object mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("BigDecimalModule", new Version(0, 1, 0, "alpha"));
module.addSerializer(ClassToBeSerialized.class, new MyCustomSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Take a look at [Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Comment: I have a List of MyClass.  I'm using Spring MVC to serialize the list to JSON.  Each instance of MyClass in the list has a BigDecimal and a Locale.  I want to serialize each BigDecimal based on the locale (which can be different for every instance).  How can I customize the SerializationConfig for every row?